# {{linkTo}} Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: ember.js

When trying to transition from my listing view to a single object view - I am getting the error:

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'JobProjectRole' of undefined'
```

I initially thought that my model was not being passed to the new view's controller, but from the stacktrace it makes me think it is something to do with the list view and unbinding?

This is the stacktrace:

```
N.unchain ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
N.remove ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
Ember.unwatch ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
Ember.removeObserver ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
(anonymous function) ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:27  
h ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
Ember.Evented.Ember.Mixin.create.trigger ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:23  
Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend.trigger ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:25  
r ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.triggerRecursively ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:27  
r ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend._notifyWillDestroyElement ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:27  
Ember.merge.destroyElement ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:28  
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.destroyElement ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:27  
r ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.willDestroy ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:27  
r ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
w.PrototypeMixin.h.create.destroy ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:24  
r ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
Ember.ContainerView.Ember.View.extend._currentViewWillChange ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:28  
h ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16 
Ember.notifyBeforeObservers ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
A ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
n ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
Ember.trySet ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
(anonymous function) ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:21  
l ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
Ember.tryFinally ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
f ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
Ember._suspendObserver ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
s._sync ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:21  
(anonymous function) ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:17  
Ember.handleErrors ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
n ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:17  
f ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:17  
l ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:17  
Ember.tryFinally ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
i.flush ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:17   
i.end ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:17  
e ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:20  
Ember.tryFinally ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
Ember.run.end ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:20  
Ember.tryFinally ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:16  
Ember.run ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:17  
(anonymous function) ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js:41  
p.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:2  
g.handle.h
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could include your code

Comment: Problem is it is such a huge file I am not sure what code to include... I cannot really see where it is falling over. Have tried removing all references to 'JobProjectRole' and it still errors.

Comment: I'm getting this too. Ever get it figured out?